# Stop Validation on Empty DateTime field returning Invalid in ModelState Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have a razor page with the following syntax

```
 <form method="post">

    <input id="Text1" type="date" asp-for="@Model.PersonModel.DOB" />

    <h2>
        Is Valid: @ModelState.IsValid
    </h2>


    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

In the code behind I have

```
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //never hits here
        }
        return Page();
    }
```

In the person model I have

```
public class PersonModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [CustomDateTime()]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}

public class CustomDateTimeAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{

    public CustomDateTimeAttribute()
    {

    }


    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return ValidationResult.Success;
        //return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }
}
```

When I enter nothing on the UI page, hit submit, if the date is empty it falls over and return Invalid, however I want it to return Valid if it empty and only return Invalid if the date is incorrect. I thought that by having he custom validator would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nullable DateTime like this:

```
public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
```

or in another form

```
public Nullable<DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
```